# Is there a way to capture the history of logs in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, logging

When getting the logs of a kubernetes node we use
`kubectl get logs -lapp=default-agent -f`
This starts streaming logs from the current time, is there any way to capture the history? If not, how are big corporations so fast in doing hot fixes, if there is no log history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--since=<duration>` parameter, see [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs).

For example `kubectl get logs -lapp=default-agent --since=1h`

> how are big corporations so fast in doing hot fixes, if there is no log history

Big corporations are using enterprise solutions such as Splunk, ELK, Loki, ...

You should get more familiar with [logging architecture in k8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#cluster-level-logging-architectures)

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why this is giving very few logs, ideally the size should be in GB. I used this exact command.

Comment: And do you know how can we capture the request in streaming logs, more efficiently? I just search for some keywords that are in my API, and if it hits, I stop..